Rate of heat flow through rod of variable conductivity
Incase wher we have an object( a rod ) with its conductivity not uniform say varying with temprature. Then will heat flow through it at same rate from every cross section of the object?

With perfect heat insulation and in the steady state, where else could the heat go?

The heat flux at any point is $q=-k\nabla T$, where $T$ solves the heat equation
$$\rho c\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}= \nabla\cdot(k\nabla T),$$
with density $\rho$, heat capacity $c$, and possibly varying thermal conductivity $k$.
At steady state, $\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}=0$, $\nabla\cdot(k\nabla T)$ is zero everywhere, and so the heat flux—also at steady state—is, as basics notes, solenoidal; meaning that it sums to zero across a closed boundary but isn't necessarily the same through any arbitrary plane.
If the rod (with uniform cross section) is insulated and lateral temperature variation is negligible, we can idealize the rod using the one-dimensional
$$\rho c\frac{\partial T}{\partial t}= \frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(k\frac{\partial T}{\partial x}\right)$$
with heat flux $q=-k\frac{dT}{dx}$ at any point. Since $k\frac{dT}{dx}=\mathrm{constant}$ at steady state (from integration of $\frac{d}{d x}\left(k\frac{d T}{d x}\right)=0$), heat does indeed flow at the same rate through each cross section at steady state. One could also arrive at this conclusion by performing an energy balance on any section of the rod, with arbitrary thermal conductivity.
Please let me know if anything’s unclear.

upvoting, as soon as the answer properly interprets the condition $\nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{q} = 0$ in 3D, with $\boldsymbol{q} = - k \nabla T$. Divergence-free vector field condition doesn't imply that the vector field is uniform, but that it is solenoidal (qualitatively, transmission with no sources, no net flux across a closed surface)

I didn't mean for "constant" to be interpreted as "uniform" but rather as "unchanging"; please see the clarifying edits.

now I can't disagree anymore +1

Could you please explain the notations used, because I am accustomed to some different notations

Can you be more specific? The links I gave contain information about operators such as $\nabla$, for example.
